# unable to print closing braces to file python while removing unprintable chars

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace unprintable characters from a line in python before writing the same to a file.

```
import re

line = 'Testing offset [4,-5]'
re.sub("[^[:print:]]", '?', line)

>> line
'Testing offset [4,-?'
```

I want the output to be like

```
'Testing offset [4,-5]'
```

Can somebody help on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by unprintable in this case?

Comment: Soemething such as Ctrl+M (Ctrl^M) characters which are not printable

Comment: `re` does not support POSIX character classes, use `regex` PyPi module instead, or convert to a regular character class.